# Ping-Tool in PyQt4 and Scapy

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4, scapy

I'm trying to make a little pinging tool with Scapy and PyQt4.
The code is fairly simple and all it does now is pinging an address the user can type in.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.sendrecv import sr, send

def q2s(qstr): return "%s" %qstr

class Application(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Application, self).__init__()
        self.resize(1000,500)
        self.centre()

        self.initGui()
        self.show()

    def initGui(self):

        self.ipAddress = QtGui.QLineEdit("1.1.1.1",self)

        self.label = QtGui.QLabel("...")
        self.label.move(50,100)
        pingBtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Ping!", self)
        pingBtn.move(50,50)

        pingBtn.clicked.connect(self.ping)

    def ping(self):
        ip = q2s(self.ipAddress.text())

        ans, unans = sr(IP(dst=ip)/ICMP(), timeout=1, verbose=0)
        if ans:
            self.label.setText("Host is up")
        else:
            self.label.setText("Host is down")

    def centre(self):
        screen = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
        sizeNow = self.geometry()
        self.move((screen.width() - sizeNow.width()) / 2, 
                  (screen.height() - sizeNow.height()) / 2)

def run():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Application()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

However, when trying to ping an IP address an error is printed to the console.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Application.py", line 71, in ping
    ans, unans = sr(IP(dst=ip)/ICMP(), timeout=1, verbose=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 317, in sr
    a,b=sndrcv(s,x,*args,**kargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 129, in sndrcv
    inp, out, err = select(inmask,[],[], remaintime)
select.error: (4, 'Unterbrechung w\xc3\xa4hrend des Betriebssystemaufrufs')
```

The last line means something like "Interruption during call of operating system".

I can not see what might be wrong about the program.

Using the send function instead of the sr function works somehow. So I think the problem might be that the application is waiting for a response. But I still don't know how to fix the error.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in Scapy: an exception we want to catch when calling `select()` is different when in multi-thread environment.

A pull-request ([#417](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/pull/417)) is currently examined (I'll update this answer when it has been merged), so you can check if the [patch](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/pull/417/files) fixes this issue for you (I hope so!).